# Why is scipy.optimize.curve_fit not producing a line of best fit for my points?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to plot several datasets for repeat R-T measurements and fit a cubic root line of best fit through each dataset using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

My code produces a line for each dataset, but not a cubic root line of best fit. Each dataset is colour-coded to its corresponding line of best fit:

[image]

I've tried increasing the order of magnitude of my data, as I heard that sometimes `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` doesn't like very small numbers, but this made no change. If anyone could point out where I am going wrong I would be extremely grateful:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
import scipy.optimize as scpo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

files = [ '50mA30%set1.lvm','50mA30%set3.lvm', '50mA30%set4.lvm', 
'50mA30%set5.lvm']

for file in files:
                                    
    data = numpy.loadtxt(file)                     
      
    current_YBCO = data[:,1] 
    voltage_YBCO = data[:,2] 
    current_thermometer = data[:,3]
    voltage_thermometer = data[:,4]
    T = data[:,5]

    R = voltage_thermometer/current_thermometer
    p = np.polyfit(R, T, 4)
    T_fit = p[0]*R**4 + p[1]*R**3 + p[2]*R**2 + p[3]*R + p[4] 
    y = voltage_YBCO/current_YBCO
    
    def test(T_fit, a, b, c): 
        return a * (T_fit+b)**(1/3) + c

    param, param_cov = curve_fit(test, np.array(T_fit), np.array(y), 
    maxfev=100000) 

    ans = (param[0]*(np.array(T_fit)+param[1])**(1/3)+param[2])

    plt.scatter(T_fit,y, 0.5)
    plt.plot(T_fit, ans, '--', label ="optimized data") 
    plt.xlabel("YBCO temperature(K)")
    plt.ylabel("Resistance of YBCO(Ohms)")
    plt.xlim(97, 102)
    plt.ylim(-.00025, 0.00015)
```

Comment: Your question would be more welcome if you posted program text as text.

Comment: Apologies for that mistake, I've now reposted the program as text

Answer (score 0):

Two things are making this harder for you.

First, cube roots of negative numbers for numpy arrays. If you try this you'll see that you aren't getting the result you want:

```py
x = np.array([-8, 0, 8])
x**(1/3)  # array([nan,  0.,  2.])
```

This means that your `test` function is going to have a problem any time it gets a negative value, and you need the negative values to create the left hand side of the curves.  Instead, use [np.cbrt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cbrt.html)

```py
x = np.array([-8, 0, 8])
np.cbrt(x) # array([-2.,  0.,  2.])
```

Secondly, your function is

```py
def test(T_fit, a, b, c):
    return a * (T_fit + b)**(1/3) + c
```

Unfortunately, this just doesn't look very much like the graph you show. This makes it really hard for the optimisation to find a "good" fit. Things I particularly dislike about this function are

- it goes vertical at `T_fit == b`. Your data has a definite slope at this point
- it keeps growing quite strongly away from `T_fit = b`. Your data goes horizontal.

However, it is *sometimes* possible to get a more "sensible fit" by giving the optimisation a good starting point.

You haven't given us any code to work from, which makes this much harder.  So, by way of illustration, try this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Generate some data which looks a bit like yours
x = np.linspace(95, 105, 1001)
y = 0.001 * (-0.5 + 1/(1 + np.exp((100-x)/0.5)) + 0.125 * np.random.rand(len(x)))

# A fitting function
def fit(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.cbrt((x + b)) + c

# Perform the fitting
param, param_cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit, x, y, p0=[0.004, -100, 0.001], maxfev=100000)

# Calculate the fitted data:
yf = fit(x, *param)
print(param)

# Plot data and the fitted curve
ax.plot(x, y, '.')
ax.plot(x, yf, '-')
```

Now, if I run this code I do get a fit which roughly follows the data. However, if I take the initial guess out, i.e. do the fitting by calling

```py
param, param_cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit, x, y, maxfev=100000)
```

then the fit is much worse.  The reason why is that `curve_fit` will start from an initial guess of `[1, 1, 1]`. The solution which looks approximately right lies in a different valley to `[1, 1, 1]` and therefore it isn't the solution which is found. Said another way, it only finds the local minimum, not the global.